# How do I move looks and dashboards between Looker instances?

Tags: looker

We have Looker production and Looker staging instances. We need a way to move looks and dashboards between them.

Answer (score 5):

At Ro we've built a tool on top of "gzr" that will help you bulk-migrate looks and dashboards between instances. For more information, see https://medium.com/ro-data-team-blog/ro-gazer-bulk-looker-content-management-ad7f96f4100